# Solutions of diophantine eq: $x^4-2x^3y+2xy^3+y^4=2s^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations, problem-solving

I'm examining solutions of this diophantine equation:

$$x^4-2x^3y+2xy^3+y^4=2s^2$$

It looks like all the solutions are of the form $(x,y,s) = (t,\pm t, \pm t^2)$ where $t$ is any integer. But how do I prove that these are all the solutions? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is unlikely to have a familiy of solutions with a single parameter to a single equation with three parameters. ¿Why do you ask, how or where did you find this problem?. ¿Do we have any reason to think that it is tractable?

Comment: Well, I came upon this equation myself examining rational distances from the corners of a polygon. Basically it's a term under a radical that I'm trying to find out can be a perfect square. I don't know if it''s tractable or not. It looked nice and symmetric, I thought maybe it had been studied before.

Comment: Let $u = x^2 - xy - y^2$ and $v = xy$ and we find $u^2 + v^2 = 2s^2$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you come up with that parametrization? was there a procedure you followed?

Comment: @individ : You missed the $2$ in $2s^2$.

Comment: @StevenGregory  Yes I was mistaken.

Comment: @StevenGregory The problem is not yet solved. With this substitution we need to solve the system of equations. For example such. $$s^2+2ps-p^2=x^2-xy-y^2$$  $$p^2+2ps-s^2=xy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want an elementary proof or not.

The following argument uses properties of elliptic curves to show the result.

Define $z=s/y^2$ and $w=x/y$ giving
\begin{equation*}
2z^2=w^4-2w^3+2w+1
\end{equation*}

This quartic has a rational solution $w=1, z=1$, so is birationally equivalent to an elliptic curve.

Define $u=1/(w-1)$, so that $w=1+1/u$ giving
\begin{equation*}
2z^2u^4=2u^4+2u+1
\end{equation*}
and set $4zu^2=g$ and $2u=h$ so that
\begin{equation*}
g^2=h^4+8h+8
\end{equation*}

This equation can be transformed to the elliptic curve
\begin{equation*}
c^2=d^3+3d^2+d
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
w=\frac{x}{y}=\frac{c+2d+1}{c-1}
\end{equation*}

Using Pari-GP, we have that the elliptic curve has $3$ finite torsion points at $(0,0)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$. Denis Simon's ellrank package tells us that the rank of the elliptic curve is zero, so the afore-mentioned points are the only rational points on the curve.

These give $w= \pm 1$ only and the partial homogeneity of the original equation gives the solutions $(t, \pm t, \pm t^2)$ as stated.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't studied elliptic curves yet, so I can't verify the last part of your answer. But looking at the definition on wikipedia, $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, whereas the curve in c and d has a $d^2$ term. Does this matter at all? Is there a text you recommend that goes over the material you used here?